# Apollo graphQL: Error decoding Array while using custom scalars in iOS swift

Tags: json, swift, graphql, apollo-ios

I have schema as show below. Here question_r is an array of dictionaries received as Json. I am facing issue converting it. Is there any way i can successfully decode it?

```
"questionR": [
                              {
                                "identifier": "123",
                                "skills": {
                                  "primary_skill": "vocabulary",
                                  "secondary_skill": "reading",
                                }
                              }
                            ]
```

**This is the schema**

```
{
            "name": "question_r",
            "description": "",
            "args": [],
            "type": {
              "kind": "SCALAR",
              "name": "Json",
              "ofType": null
            },
            "isDeprecated": false,
            "deprecationReason": null
          }
}
```

**My script looks like this:**

SCRIPT_PATH="${PODS_ROOT}/Apollo/scripts"
cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"
"${SCRIPT_PATH}"/run-bundled-codegen.sh codegen:generate --target=swift --includes=./**/*.graphql --passthroughCustomScalars --localSchemaFile="schema.json" API.swift

**This is the typealias where i am defining Json. It can ve dictionary or array of dictionary**

```
public typealias Json = [String:Any?]

extension Dictionary: JSONDecodable {
    public init(jsonValue value: JSONValue) throws {
        guard let dictionary = value as? Dictionary else {
            throw JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: value, to: Dictionary.self)
        }
        self = dictionary
    }
}

extension Array: JSONDecodable{
    public init(jsonValue value: JSONValue) throws {
        guard let array = value as? Array else {throw JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: value, to: Array.self)}
        self = array
    }
}
```

Any workaround for this? Am i missing something here?

Comment: not valid json, missing outer object brackets

Comment: @xadm Thats not the issue. Anyways edited the response here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by assuming Json to be an array and converting a dictionary to array.

```
public typealias Json = [[String:Any?]]

extension Json: JSONDecodable{
 
    public init(jsonValue value: JSONValue) throws{
        guard let array = value as? Array else {
            guard let dict = value as? Dictionary<String, Any> else { throw JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: value, to: Dictionary<String, Any>.self)
            }
            self = .init(arrayLiteral: dict)
            return
        }
        self = array
    }
}
```

This works for me.